# SAS - Create Table

Tags: sas

I have two models that have output:

```
output out=m1 pred=p1;
output out=m2 pred=p2;
```

They run fine and create the below sample observations:

Sample of M2

```
Obs       p1

  1    0.98057
  2    0.71486
  3    0.91951
  4    0.93073
  5    0.93505
  6    0.98788
  7    0.94461
  8    0.99449
  9    0.93282
 10    0.88654
```

AND

Sample of M1

```
Obs       p2

  1    0.97988
  2    0.70704
  3    0.91731
  4    0.92880
  5    0.93324
  6    0.98746
  7    0.94386
  8    0.99431
  9    0.93102
 10    0.88404
```

Next I try to combine the two into a table with the statement:

```
proc sql;
create table ptable as select *
from m1 as a left join m2 as b on a.cnt=b.cnt;
quit;
```

But I'm getting this error:
ERROR: Column cnt could not be found in the table/view identified with the correlation name A.
ERROR: Column cnt could not be found in the table/view identified with the correlation name A.
ERROR: Column cnt could not be found in the table/view identified with the correlation name B.
ERROR: Column cnt could not be found in the table/view identified with the correlation name B.

So how do I put p1 and p2 into a table in SAS?

Below is the code used to generate p1 and p2 where DATA = source

```
/*initial model*/
proc hplogistic data=DATA;
model value(event='1')=X1-X20;
output out=m1 pred=p1;
run;

/*new model*/
proc hplogistic data=data;
model value(event='1')=X1-X20;
output out=m2 pred=p2;
run;
```

Comment: join them on OBS since there apparently is no CNT variable.

Comment: How did you get SAS to create an output datasets with only one variable? What procedure did you run? Show your code, log etc.

Comment: I added the two models code that generate p1 and p2 above. I tried merging on obs with a.Obs=b.Obs and got the same error

Comment: Add some ID or COPYVARS= variables to include variables that will uniquely identify your observations and then you can merge on that variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for performing a merge **without** a `by` statement.  The tables will be joined row-by-row.

For example

```
data have1(keep=p1) have2(keep=p2);
  do _n_ = 1 to 10;
    p1 = 1 / _n_;
    p2 = _n_ ** 2;
    output;
  end;
run;

data want;
  merge have1 have2;
  *** NO BY STATEMENT ***;
run;
proc print data=want;run;
-------- OUTPUT --------
Obs       p1       p2

  1    1.00000      1
  2    0.50000      4
  3    0.33333      9
  4    0.25000     16
  5    0.20000     25
  6    0.16667     36
  7    0.14286     49
  8    0.12500     64
  9    0.11111     81
 10    0.10000    100
```

Merges without BY is atypical in the data processing that **I** normally do.

Comment: Hi Richard, this appears close, but I need to be able to name the table, show all aboservations, and p1 and p2 have to remain unchanged. I think there is a version of this that would give me exactly what I need.

Comment: I refer you to @Tom comment, we would need more detail on the actual situation.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I added the model codes to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that ran the whole way through:

```
/*initial model*/
proc hplogistic data=DATA;
model value(event='1')=X1-X20;
output out=m1 pred=p1 copyvars=(cnt readmit);
run;

/*new model*/
proc hplogistic data=data;
model value(event='1')=X1-X20;
output out=m2 pred=p2 copyvar=cnt;
run;
```

cnt had to be included in the output to be joined in the table.